CSAPP: Figure 8-37 An improved version of Figure 8.36 that correctly accounts for the fact that signals are not queued
When I was reading Chapter 8 Correct Signal Handling in CSAPP, I did not quite understand the improvement in Figure 8-36. In the improved Figure 8-37, the original book used while instead of if to correctly account for the fact that signals are not queued.
My understanding is that Figure 8-36 uses if to complete a SIGCHLD, thereby recycling a child process, but this assumes that the signal is queued. In Figure 8-37, while is used, so that SIGCHLD can be used to recycle multiple child processes at a time, which is what the original book says about reclaiming as many zombie processes as possible.
In addition, I also learned that the handler2 program is executed concurrently with the main program, that is, multi-threaded execution. In this regard, I am not sure what the concurrent execution flow of these two programs is like.
my two questions are:
1.why while is useful?
2.what the concurrent execution flow of the main and handler2 is like?
Here is the original code
/*  figure 8-36  */
/* WARNING: This code is buggy! */
void handler1(int sig) 
{
    int olderrno = errno;

    if ((waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        sio_error("waitpid error");
    Sio_puts("Handler reaped child\n");
    Sleep(1);
    errno = olderrno;
}

int main() 
{
    int i, n;
    char buf[MAXBUF];

    if (signal(SIGCHLD, handler1) == SIG_ERR)
        unix_error("signal error");

    /* Parent creates children */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (Fork() == 0) {
            printf("Hello from child %d\n", (int)getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    /* Parent waits for terminal input and then processes it */
    if ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0)
        unix_error("read");

    printf("Parent processing input\n");
    while (1)
        ;

    exit(0);
}

/* figure 8-37 An improved version of Figure 8.36 that correctly accounts for the fact that signals are not queued */
void handler2(int sig) 
{
    int olderrno = errno;

    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) > 0) {
        Sio_puts("Handler reaped child\n");
    }
    if (errno != ECHILD)
        Sio_error("waitpid error");
    Sleep(1);
    errno = olderrno;
}


I don't see a question or problem description in your post. Please [edit] it and tell us what you need help with.

What's Fork, what's Sleep, is this pseudo code?

CSAPP makes a simple encapsulation of fork and sleep, adds some error checking mechanisms, and achieves the same effect as before



why while is useful?


Regular signals do not queue, which means, for example, that if a SIGCHLD is delivered to a process that already has SIGCHLD pending, then that second SIGCHLD is effectively lost.  Thus, at times you may have multiple terminated children ready to be collected, but only one SIGCHLD to alert you to that.  The while provides for collecting all of those in such a case, whereas the version with if collects only one child per signal-handler execution, which may leave some uncollected.


what the concurrent execution flow of the main and handler2 is like?


Signal handling does not introduce any concurrency.  Signals are handled asynchronously, which means that the regular control flow of your program will be temporarily suspended while signal handling is performed in its place, until the handler returns or the program terminates.  When (if) the main control flow resumes, it might see a system call fail on account of the interruption, or it might see no direct effect of the interruption at all.  That depends in part on where the main control flow was interrupted, what handlers are installed, and how the installed handlers are configured.
